# cytoscape.js : blurry lables when zooming out

Tags: cytoscape.js

[screenshot of the visualizer showing barely readble lables,although the size isnt too small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiCvO.png)

here is my node style :

```
.selector('node')
  .css({

     'content': 'data(id)', 
     'width':55,
     'height':20,
     'shape':'ELLIPSE',
     'color':'black',
     'background-color':'yellow',
     'text-valign' :'center',
     'min-zoomed-font-size':1,
     'font-size':8,
     'font-weight':'normal'

  })
```

is there a way to get more clear lables on lower zooming levels?

Answer (score 1):

The browser controls font rendering.  It's not possible to modify font antialiasing.

The only thing you can control is which font is used to render text.  So, you may want to try experimenting with different fonts.  Some tend to scale better than others.